# How to find if a file exists in expect script

Tags: expect

I have a statement inside my expect script like this

```
send "sed -i -e 's/$oldport/$newport/' backup.txt\r"
expect "$ "
```

However I wish to first check whether the file backup.txt exist and if it does, then edit it.

How do I acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since expect is an extension of Tcl, [all Tcl commands](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm) are available to use:

```
if {[file exists backup.txt]} {
    send "sed -i -e 's/$oldport/$newport/' backup.txt\r"
    expect "$ "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick approach by using **ls**

```
set file "backup.txt"
send "ls $file\r"
expect {
        "\r\n$file" {puts "\nfile exists"}
        "cannot access $file" {puts "\nfile not found"}
}
```

You can just replace `puts "\nfile exists"` with your statement.

Answer (score 0):

A Slightly modified @asdone's solution.
Works on remote, unlike @glenn jackman’s that tests for the file in local system, on which the expect script is running.

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect --

    # settings
    set prompt "\$ " 
    set filename 'example-file.txt'
    set response__file_not_found "No such file or directory*$prompt"
    set response__file_exists "$filename*$prompt"



    send "ls $filename\r"
    expect {
        $response__file_not_found {
            puts "\n\nFile not found\n\n”
            # must exit as the negative response matches both cases 
            exit
        }
        $response__file_exists {
            puts "\n\nFile exists\n\n"
        }

    }
```